# Magento 2 - Page title prefix and suffix not rendering

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configuration, seo, page-title

I am using Magento version 2.1.4

I added page title prefix and suffix (both just for test) in Admin Panel -> Content -> Configuration -> HTML Head input fields but none of them are actually renderen in pages. I di:compiles, deployed static files after changes, cleared the cache, reindexed, refreshed, everything but still no success.

I am writing my own theme but I have not overwritten title nor in layout xml files, nor phtml files.

The only head title that is showing in pages is the page/category/product title and that is all. No prefix, no suffix.

Is this a Magento version bug or I just have forgotten to enable/change something?

**Update:**
I updated Magento to 2.1.5 version but the problem did not solve.

Comment: Have you tried using the default theme?

Comment: The same on both default templates - blank and luma

Comment: I tried it at my end as well. Seems like its a Bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't working because the inserted value was starting with a blank space. Try to trim the suffix.
Ex "- my website" instead of " - my website"
Hope it helps